# EM- waves in anisotropic medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation

When ElectroMagnetic waves from vacuum enter the anisotropic medium. If the $\epsilon$(permittivity) matrix is diagonal (with not all diagonal entries being equal). There'll be two waves in the anisotropic medium. How do we find the direction of two waves? Can you at least describe it for normal incidence?

Answer (score 0):

To kick things off, this

> If the $\epsilon$ (permittivity) matrix is diagonal (with not all diagonal entries being equal)

is not an invariant statement: this is to say, that property (having unequal diagonal entries but no off-diagonal elements) will only hold in certain specific frames of reference.

Moving on, this

> How do we find the direction of two waves?

is unclear.

- Do you mean the direction of polarization? If so, then the special directions of polarization of those 'two waves' are precisely the directions of the axes of the special frames of reference in which the permittivity tensor is diagonal.
- Do you mean the direction of propagation? Then any direction orthogonal to the direction of polarization will work (though things do get a bit more complicated if you attempt to propagate a beam at nontrivial angles within its plane of polarization).